# Run python scripts in windows

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) on my Windows 10 to install `Python 3.6`.

I now want to run some Python scripts like `test.py`.

As far as I understood, I need to initialize some system variables, but I am not really able to get the whole meaning. I can set system variables by typing `sysdm.cpl` at the start button. Is this the right way? Otherwise?

Comment: anaconda should set most of the env variables to get the python setup up and running.  but, sysdm.cpl can be used to set additional system/env variables in windows.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set env variables permanently, then yes, this is the right way (start->sysdm.cpl->advanced->Environment variables)

If you want to set some variables for just one particular session,  then open cmd.exe and set variables like

```
set _variable_=_value_
```

and then run your script.

Answer (score 1):

[image] 1- open cmd

2-use cd to go to the file where your script is located(**cd.. to go to previous folder and cd name to go to another folder**)

3-when you get there in cmd type

4-python filename.py

if you are using anaconda instead of cmd use anaconda prompt

---

adding python to path:

1-open windows explorer

2-on the left side left click this pc and choose properties

3-then go to advanced system settings

4-then at the bottom enviorment variables

5-if you are windows 10 there will be onedrive written at top and behind it path choose path

6-then click new

7-add python directory to the path and then python directory/scripts

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk check this

Comment: This is simply not true :)

Comment: why?? i use this way

Comment: I had already tried this way, and python is not recognized as a command nor program nor a batch file.

Comment: than python is not in your path

Comment: you are using python 3 or 2?

Comment: Let me guess: does this mean that I have to set a system variable?

Comment: exactly you guessed it which python version are you using

Comment: Python 3.6 version

Comment: where it is located

Comment: Well, Anaconda is located at `C:\Users\My_Name\Anaconda3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150188/discussion-between-py-ser-and-burhan-asif).